# How to get focal length data from proprietary file formats (CR2, ARW, etc)?

Tags: raw, software, metadata

I'm looking for a way to read the equivalent of EXIF data (focal length, camera make, etc) from RAW file formats, preferably with javascript. I've managed to read EXIF from JPG's, but there don't appear to be any libraries for RAW formats.

I've viewed this resource and I'm aware of file "tags" (http://lclevy.free.fr/cr2/), but I'm not sure how to read these with javascript.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: vtc b/c This is a question about programming libraries for javascript.

Comment: Try searching for an ExifTool wrapper for javascript.

Comment: How hard did you look?

Comment: Normaly also the most proprietary file formats are documented well enough to extract this information out of the file by yourself. mostly the metadata are stored in a fixed pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Phil Harvey's  "exiftool" will do this. It's a command line tool written in Perl.
 [exiftool](https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/)